# 3ware 8506, Solaris (Nexenta Core) and the tw driver: driver (tw) successfully added to system but failed to attach

Tags: drivers, sata, nexenta, 3ware

I've got a little Nexenta Core box at home that's doing NAS duties. Recently, I bought a second hand 3ware 8506 12-port SATA controller to go with the Supermicro AOC-SAT2-MV8 controller that I already have, which should allow me to go to more than 8 drives. Motherboard is an old Iwill DK8N.

The problem I have is trying to get Nexenta to see the controller. Originally, I assumed that the OS had the driver already, but running the `tw_cli` utility showed that there were `no controllers found`. After an age arsing around with JVMs and suchlike, I managed to get the 9.5.3 version of the `tw` driver installed in `/usr/kernel/drv/` and `/usr/kernel/drv/amd64`. However, when I try and add the driver I get the following:

```
$ add_drv -c scsi -i "pci13c1,1001" tw
devfsadm: driver failed to attach: tw
Warning: Driver (tw) successfully added to system but failed to attach
```

`dmesg` shows a bit more detail:

```
Apr 28 15:14:16 storebot pcplusmp: [ID 805372 kern.info] pcplusmp: ide (ata) instance 0 irq 0xe vector 0x46 ioapic 0x2 intin 0xe is bound to cpu 0
Apr 28 15:14:16 storebot unix: [ID 954099 kern.info] NOTICE: IRQ20 is being shared by drivers with different interrupt levels.
Apr 28 15:14:16 storebot This may result in reduced system performance.
Apr 28 15:14:16 storebot tw: [ID 716744 kern.warning] WARNING: tw0: Attach failed 0001
Apr 28 15:14:16 storebot pcplusmp: [ID 805372 kern.info] pcplusmp: ide (ata) instance 1 irq 0xf vector 0x46 ioapic 0x2 intin 0xf is bound to cpu 1
Apr 28 15:14:16 storebot pcplusmp: [ID 805372 kern.info] pcplusmp: pci-ide (pci-ide) instance 2 irq 0x1b vector 0x46 ioapic 0x3 intin 0x3 is bound to cpu 0
Apr 28 15:14:16 storebot pcplusmp: [ID 805372 kern.info] pcplusmp: pci-ide (pci-ide) instance 2 irq 0x1b vector 0x46 ioapic 0x3 intin 0x3 is bound to cpu 1
```

After this, the driver is listed in `modinfo|grep 3ware`

```
193 fffffffff85a1000   6ea8 353   1  tw (3ware SCSI HBA 1.12)
```

I get the same IRQ error on boot, but it's never affected performance in the past. The 8506 is in the last PCI-X slot on the motherboard (other things in this box are: a) the aforementioned Supermicro Sata controller, an Intel Quad-port Gigabit NIC and an Emulex 2GB FC card).

The other weirdness is that after the driver has been loaded, the `tw_cli` utility now just hangs using 100% CPU with no output.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this setup fundamentally incompatible for some reason?